# Styling Joomla Content -- Drop Caps CSS

Tags: css, joomla

I have tried various ways to apply drop-caps to a Joomla article. Nothing works.

I assumed that I just needed to paste the drop-caps style (see below) into template.css and that I could then apply the class to the phrase ONCE UPON A TIME... as follows:

```
<p class="introduction">O</p><p>nce upon a time...</p>
```

I am probably missing something very simple, but I can't figure it out. Additional info: text editor is tinyMCE; template uses multiple style sheets.

```
p.introduction:first-letter 
{
 font-size: 44px;
 float: left; 
color: #D4D4C7;
 line-height: 35px;
 padding-top: 3px; 
 padding-right: 3px;
 font-family: Times, serif, Georgia;
}
```

Comment: what exactly you want to do ?

Comment: Why do you split the paragraph in two paragraphs?

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping the first letter in a span and display it as
Inline block. That should allow you to style the first letter however you like. it should still sit inline.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use simple jQuery to get first letter of article and put it into floated div at the top of article.

Your HTML should be pretty the same:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="drop-caps"></div>

    <p>Once upon a time lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nibh fuga quam at ut, justo ante nullam urna est, turpis...</p>
</div>
```

Css rules for Drop Caps (Big Capital letter):

```
.drop-caps {
    padding: 0 10px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 48px;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 48px;
}
```

and jQuery:

```
    var firstSentence = $('.content').find('p:first').text();
    $('.content').find('.drop-caps').append(firstSentence.charAt(0));

    if ($('.drop-caps + div').length) {
        $('.drop-caps').hide();
    }
```

Here is actual [JSFfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zahorodnyk/4x0qsv08/3/).